# Task List Sharepoint 2010

Tags: tasks, task-list

I have got a Task List. I want to give rights only one person, to create task. But if any of user choose this task, only he should edit this task. How should I do this. Manager could edit all tasks.

Comment: use event receiver and add item level permissions after breaking inheritance

Comment: But How Programically ? Or in Managing Panel ? Where should I find this ?

Comment: You said that when an user "chooses" the task, from that point onward the user must be allowed to edit that task. But how do you intend to make the user "chose" the task in the first place? Can you elaborate some more on the complete user story?

Comment: We have got a list of task. From the Box Sharepoint 2010. And when some of users find out on the task list the task which is good for him he will take it. 

But how to do this, when User take a task, nothink more then him can edit this task ?